# How to run a test project twice using Selenium C# with NUnit

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, devops, nunit-3.0

I have a test project which is developed using selenium c# with Nunit. It is integrated with the Build process (CI).

As per the business rule, I have to test the application with two profiles
1. Admin
2. Agent

Which means I have to execute all the selenium tests once with Admin role and re-run all those tests again with Agent role.

```
class TestCases
{
    string user = string.Empty;
    ChromeDriver d;

    [SetUp]
    public void setup()
    {
        d = new ChromeDriver();
        d.Url = "https://www.example.com/";
        user = d.FindElement(By.Id("Role")).Text; //Admin or Agent
    }


    [Test]
    public void TestCaseID_1()
    {
        if (user.Equals("Admin") || user.Equals("Agent"))
        {
            // code
        }
    }


    [Test]
    public void TestCaseID_2()
    {
        if (user.Equals("Agent"))
        {
            // code
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestCaseID_3()
    {
        if (user.Equals("Admin"))
        {
            //change user role from Admin to Agent
        }
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void tearrdown()
    {
        d.Dispose();
        d.Quit();
    }
}
```

I am looking for something like this: 
1. All the tests should first run as an Admin.
2. In the last test, Admin should degrade his role from Admin to Agent.
3. Now, Re-run all the tests once again for an Agent.

Currently, I am able to test the application either as an Admin or as an Agent.

I am kind of confused on how to re-run those scripts for a new profile (Agent). Kindly help me out.

Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Test case attribute available in Nunit refer this link [here](http://nunit.org/docs/2.6/testCase.html)

Then your testmethod can be take a parameter as userRole. Now the testmethod will be run twice with parameter both these roles.

```
[TestCase("Admin")]
[TestCase("Agent")]   
 public void UnitTestName(string userRole)
{
//Arrange

//Act

//Assert
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I had updated sample code of what i am expecting. Could you please revisit my ask again.